# Find a limit of sequence using the definition of a limit (Cauchy)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n \to\infty } \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3}{n^4}$$
I need to find a limit of this sequence. May be I should use the formula of this sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$, but I don't know how to get n from the whole expression.

Comment: Do you know the sum of cubes formula?

Comment: yes, I know, but I don't know what to do next

Comment: Use $f(x)=x^3$ and note that you are after the limit of $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}n\right)$. Does this ring a bell?

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't learned limits of the functions yet. Just limits of the sequences

Comment: @MargaritaHolt So you haven't yet studied Riemann integral, Riemann sums and etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 =\frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{4} \implies \lim_{n \to\infty } \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3}{n^4} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n^4+2n^3+n^2)}{4n^4}=\frac{1}{4}
$$